# Add files in sub folders to target

Tags: cmake

I'd like to add output files in subdirectory to a build target.
I wrote in `CMakeLists.txt` like below:

```
file(GLOB srcfiles "src/*.txt")
add_custom_target(subtask ALL)
set(dest_dir ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sub/)
foreach(srcfile ${srcfiles})
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^.*/(.*).txt$" filename ${srcfile})
  add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${dest_dir}/${filename}.txt
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ARGS -E make_directory ${dest_dir}
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/process.sh ARGS ${srcfile}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/process.sh)
    add_dependencies(subtask ${dest_dir}/${filename}.txt)
endforeach(srcfile)
```

And executed:

```
mkdir build && cmake .. && make
```

But `sub/*.txt` are not created after build.

How should I do to build all commands on build?

**updated (2017/2/4)**

I solved the issue: use `add_custom_command` for each target and then declare `add_custom_target` that depends on all targets of `add_custom_command`.

```
set(TARGET_FILES "")
file(GLOB SRC_FILES "src/*.txt")
foreach(SRC_FILE ${SRC_FILES})
  string(REGEX REPLACE "^.*/(.*).txt$" "\\1-foo.txt" TARGET_FILE ${SRC_FILE})
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sub/${TARGET_FILE}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} ARGS -E make_directory ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sub
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/process.sh ARGS ${SRC_FILE}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/process.sh)
  list(APPEND TARGET_FILES "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sub/${TARGET_FILE}")
endforeach()
add_custom_target(foo_txt ALL DEPENDS ${TARGET_FILES})
```

Comment: I solved the issue:

```
set(TARGET_FILES "")
file(GLOB SRC_FILES "src/*.txt")
foreach(SRC_FILE ${SRC_FILES})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you are trying to achieve, but just from looking at it I would say it should be:

```
set(dest_dir ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sub)
add_custom_target(
    subtask ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${dest_dir}
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/process.sh
)
```

Only if the `output.txt` is an input for something else, you need a custom command:

```
set(dest_dir ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sub)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${dest_dir}/output.txt
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${dest_dir}
    COMMAND ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/process.sh
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/process.sh
)
add_custom_target(
    subtask ALL 
    DEPENDS ${dest_dir}/output.txt 
)
```

Note that the default working directory for those commands is `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR`.

**Edit:** I think the problem in your code is the use of [`add_dependencies()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) for file level dependencies. But `add_dependencies()` can only be used to declare target dependencies.

**Edit:** With a `foreach()` you can either collect the dependencies or `APPEND` them with to a dummy output. The first looks something like this:

```
file(GLOB srcfiles "src/*.txt")
set(dest_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sub")
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY "${dest_dir}")
foreach(srcfile ${srcfiles})
    get_filename_component(filename "${srcfile}" NAME_WE)
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT "${dest_dir}/${filename}.txt"
        COMMAND ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/process.sh ${srcfile}
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY "${srcfile}"
        DEPENDS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/process.sh"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${dest_dir}"
    )
    list(APPEND subtask_deps "${dest_dir}/${filename}.txt")
endforeach(srcfile)
add_custom_target(
    subtask ALL
    DEPENDS ${subtask_deps}
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'd like to skip executing `process.sh` if `output.txt` already exists or there is no update on `process.sh` same as the behavior of `add_executable`. Is that possible in your solution?

Comment: @furushchev Sure. Is `process.sh` run from your source directory and does output into the source directory? Or how does `process.sh` know where to put `output.txt`?

Comment: @furushchev Added `MAIN_DEPENDENCY` for the "trigger a rebuild on `process.sh` changes" part. And yes, any non-existing output will trigger a rebuild too. Btw outputs are also added to the `clean` target.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Actual my use case is adding dependencies incrementally in `foreach` loop. I updated my question to follow your advice and use `foreach`. However it still skips commands we set in `add_custom_command`.

Comment: @furushchev I was thinking about why your code isn't working as-is and I think the main problem in your code is the use of [`add_dependencies()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) for file level dependencies. But `add_dependencies()` can only be used to declare target dependencies.

Comment: Sorry for very late reply and now the last did the trick! Thank you very much!